# ZoomBox in Openlayers 3/4

Tags: openlayers

I want to bind ZoomBox function to a toolbar button to active and deactivate, its default activator is Shift key. Is there a way to activate without pressing the shift key?

In OpenLayers 2 I could add the ZoomBox function using:

```
self.zb = new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({
        title: "Zoom box: zoom clicking and dragging",
        text: "Zoom"
});
self.map.addControl(self.zb);
```

and to active:

```
this.zb.activate();
```

I can't find the ZoomBox objects under ol.control class in Openlayers 4. Is there a ZoomBox equivalent or alternative in OpenLayers 4. If not how can I do this programmatically?

Comment: It looks like you took the [Tour] but nobody has yet alerted you that, for questions that involve code, we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zoombox control you are looking for has been changed to `ol.interaction.DragZoom`

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.DragZoom.html

You can configure the toolbar button to add or remove the interaction using `addInteraction()`or `removeInteraction()` but this method still needs the default shift key to activate.

**Edit:** Interaction conditions can be modified using `ol.events.condition`. You can find more information on this in the api doc [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.events.condition.html)

Adding the `ol.events.condition.always` should help you in what you are trying to achieve.

```
var dragZoom = new ol.interaction.DragZoom({
  condition: ol.events.condition.always
});
map.addInteraction(dragZoom);
```

You can add or remove the interaction by adding an onclick event to a toggle button

```
var toggleState = 0;

$("#toggleZoom").click(function () {

    if( toggleState == 0) {
        map.addInteraction(dragZoom);
        toggleState = 1;
    }
    else {
        map.removeInteraction(dragZoom);
        toggleState = 0;
    }

});
```

Comment: is there anyway to activate it programatically without press shift key?

Comment: Updated my answer. Check the edit.